# Variadic template question in piece-wise constructor of std::pair

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

```
// TEMPLATE CONSTRUCTOR pair::pair(tuple, tuple, sequence, sequence)
template<class _Ty1,
    class _Ty2>
    template<class _Tuple1,
        class _Tuple2,
        size_t... _Indexes1,
        size_t... _Indexes2> inline
        pair<_Ty1, _Ty2>::pair(_Tuple1& _Val1,
            _Tuple2& _Val2,
            index_sequence<_Indexes1...>,
            index_sequence<_Indexes2...>)
        : first(_STD get<_Indexes1>(_STD move(_Val1))...),
            second(_STD get<_Indexes2>(_STD move(_Val2))...)
        {   // construct from pair of tuples
        }

// TEMPLATE CONSTRUCTOR pair::pair(piecewise_construct_t, tuple, tuple)
template<class _Ty1,
    class _Ty2>
    template<class... _Types1,
        class... _Types2> inline
        pair<_Ty1, _Ty2>::pair(piecewise_construct_t,
            tuple<_Types1...> _Val1,
            tuple<_Types2...> _Val2)
        : pair(_Val1, _Val2,
            index_sequence_for<_Types1...>(),
            index_sequence_for<_Types2...>())
        {   // construct from pair of tuples
        }
```

The above is the source code of tuple in VisualStudio.  It is the piece-wise constructor of std::pair.  The second constructor calls the first one.  In the first constructor, data member first and second are initialized by

```
first(_STD get<_Indexes1>(_STD move(_Val1))...), second(_STD get<_Indexes2>(_STD move(_Val2))...)
```

I don't understand why std::move can be used here.  What if some arguments in the tuple is not an rvalue?  Wouldn't it make arguments that are lvalues to become rvalues and invoke unintended constructor of first and second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first constructor is not part of the interface. It's only called for delegation by the second one, where `_Val1` and `_Val2` are passed by value, so the first constructor can move them.

Because of the `std::move` call, the overloads of `std::get` that can get called here are:

```
template< std::size_t I, class... Types >
typename std::tuple_element<I, tuple<Types...> >::type&&
get( tuple<Types...>&& t ) noexcept;

template< std::size_t I, class... Types >
typename std::tuple_element<I, tuple<Types...> >::type const&&
get( const tuple<Types...>&& t ) noexcept;
```

In both cases, if `typename std::tuple_element<I, tuple<Types...> >::type` is an lvalue reference, the return type stays an lvalue reference because `T& &&` is just `T&`. So no move can occur on lvalue reference elements of the tuple.

Comment: If one of the arguments of the variadic arguments is a reference type, it will still be a reference type referring to the same reference even though the tuple is passed by value.  Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Although I don't see the problem with that.

Comment: If an argument arg0 of the variadic arguments is a reference type, wouldn't calling move() on the pass-by-value tuple make arg0 an rvalue and leaving it in an invalid state after calling the first constructor?

Comment: `std::move(T<U&>)` doesn't return a `T<U&&>&&`, it returns a `T<U&>&&`. What happens to the `U&` after that depends on what `std::get` does in this case, which I've clarified.